# Removing "google doodle" using localhost chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-doodle

How do I remove animated google doodle using localhost chrome extension?
Obviously I cannot comment so ....

Answer (score 0):

If you have loaded jquery with content-scripts in manifest.json then this is quite easy by adding to 
content.js a line:

```
$( "div#lga" ).replaceWith( "<h2>Freedom!</h2>" );
```